# Упростить код добавлением функции или функций

Tags: c, массивы, функции

Из исходного массива символов, заполненного случайным образом символами с кодами в диапазоне от 21 до 254(по ASCII), выделяются в отдельные массивы символы цифр и знаков препинания.
Нужно заменить циклы for на функцию или функции.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

#define M   32
#define MIN 21
#define MAX 254
#define random (MIN + (rand() % (MAX - MIN)))

int main(void)
{
    unsigned arr[M],
             puncts[M] = {0},
             digits[M] = {0},
             ip = 0,
             id = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        printf("%d. %c\n", i+1, (arr[i] = random));

    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        if(isdigit(arr[i]))
        {
            digits[id++] = arr[i];
            continue;
        }
        else if(ispunct(arr[i]))
        {
            puncts[ip++] = arr[i];
            continue;
        }

    printf("Puncts:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < ip; i++)
        printf("%c ", puncts[i]);

    printf("\nDigits:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < id; i++)
        printf("%c ", digits[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: и в чём у вас проблема?

Comment: Для начала стоило бы "упростить код" путем выкидывания из него бессмысленных `continue`. К чему они там? Подгонять цикл, на случай, если он задремлет как старая лошадка?

Comment: А сокрытие вызова функции за именем макро, которое выглядит как имя переменной - `random` - это тоже попытка "упрощения кода"?